# JQuery toggle on class name

Tags: jquery, toggle

I get the following HTML returned, I want to apply a simple toggle on ITEM (onclick) we show child elements marked as ITEMSUB

```
  <dl id="someID">
    <dt>Label</dt>
    <dd class="ITEM"> ITEM </dd>
    <dd class="ITEMSUB"> ITEMSUB 1 </dd>
    <dd class="ITEMSUB"> ITEMSUB 2 </dd>
    <dd class="ITEMSUB"> ITEMSUB 3 </dd>
    <dd class="ITEMSUB"> ITEMSUB 4 </dd>
  </dl>
```

I know this would be easy by having a simple list, however I cannot modify the HTML returned, thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `ul` and `li`'s instead of `dt` and `dd`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the page loads the below css will set the class `ITEMSUB` to `display:none`

```
    .ITEMSUB
        {
             display:none;
         }
```

and you can toggle using the below jquery

```
       $(".ITEM").click(function() {
              $(".ITEMSUB").toggle();
              });
```

if you want smooth transition you can use `slideToggle()`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
$(".ITEM").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".ITEMSUB").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, so simple, I kind of managed to get this working, but your solution is much more elegant, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple enough using jQuery

```
$(".ITEM").click(function() {
    $(".ITEMSUB").toggle(); 
});
```